# How to auto increment the number of students attending the specific course?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple student application and want that one row in my table shows the number of students attending the specific course (that is,  each time I approve certain application, the number of students attending that course should be auto incremented by 1). I have tried everything, sessions, linq, but was not able to do it. Here is some of my code, any suggestion is more then welcomed:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int IdCourse { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}


public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Student.Include(b => b.Course).ToList());
    }



@using StudentCourse.Models
@model List<Student>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 <table>
      <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>NumberOfStudents</th>    
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Course.Title<td>
            <td>@item.Course.NumberOfStudents</td>
        </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

When a student selects a certain course, I should Approve or reject hers/his application (Status property):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.Status, "Accepted", false) Accepted
@Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.Status, "Rejected", true) Rejected
```

The number of approved applications should be shown by auto incrementation in:

```
<td>@item.Course.NumberOfStudents</td>
```

Comment: sorry, mistake with translation, public int IdCourse in Student class

Comment: Instead of writing comments about typos in the question you should just edit the question to fix the mistake. There is an **edit** link below the question.

Comment: @Žare Labud you can edit your question to correct any mistakes you made while writing it

Comment: i did it, mea culpa, sorry, completely new to c# mvc but very enthusiastic:)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete, but if I get what you want, do the following:

1. when you click on the Accept button from the view,
2. parse the current course ID to it and then route it to a controller method.
3. When it gets there, you can collect the sent course ID,
4. then fetch that particular course from the DB,
5. get the current number of students, convert to int(if necessary), increment it and then update that fetched row on the DB

Comment: tnx will try that! - can you maybe write me some code, just for orientation?

Comment: sure, I'm currently at work. I will get the codes for each of the steps and write them here. Do you use Entityframework or Nhibernate as your ORM?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the number of student updated by updating it on the Set part of Students like this:

```
public class Course
{
    private ICollection<Student> _students;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            return _students;
        }
        set
        {

            _students = value;
            NumberOfStudents = _students?.Count ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This means that you don't need to save information to the database to update the numberOfStudents. You can also do the Count property of students on the get part of NumberOfStudents.

Comment: tnx any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: @ŽareLabud Glad to help